# Email messages going to spam folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a community portal, in which user creates his/her account. After successfull registration a confirmation mail is send on registered email address.

I am using the following code to send the mail -

```
private void SendMail(string recvr, string recvrName, string verCode, int NewUserID)
{
    try
    {
        string emailID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebMasterMail"];
        string mailPass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pass"];
        string mailer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailer"];

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress addrFrom = new MailAddress(emailID, "Panbeli.in.... Bari community portal");
        MailAddress addrTo = new MailAddress(recvr, recvrName);

        msg.To.Add(addrTo);
        msg.From = addrFrom;
        msg.Subject = "You have registered sucessfully on PanBeli.in.";
        msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        msg.Body = RegisterMessageBody(recvrName, verCode,NewUserID);
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(mailer);
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(emailID, mailPass);
        smtp.Send(msg);
    }
    catch (Exception Ex) { }
}
```

While testing we found that all the confirmation mails are going to SPAM folder instead of Inbox.

Is there anything wrong with the code or is there anything related to security.

Can anybody suggest solution to this problem.

Thanks for sharing your time.

Comment: Try adding the address as a trusted sender

Comment: I don't see how this is programming-related...

Comment: Your code isn't so much the issue as the resulting email and headers.  Further, what is flagging it as spam; outlook, gmail, the user's ISP?  Each will use a different method for detecting spam.

Comment: Is it marked as spam on the recipient server (e.g. Gmail) or by email client (Outlook)?

Comment: @Chris S: What to set address as trusted sender?

Comment: @Artem : We have checked it on Gmail and Yahoo, web based as well as configured in outlook.

Comment: @IrfanRaza try changing the title of the question, or asking on another site. If you want to avoid your email being marked as spam the basic procedure is: (1) have a trusted domain, (2) add the appropriate headers, (3) see 1

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It sounds like your email is getting flagged by SpamAssassin or the like, so you just need to focus on changing your email enough to not get flagged.

- Your content doesn't sound like it has any reason to rate high for the Bayesian score, so I don't think thats the problem. It wouldn't hurt to try removing possible trigger words though.
- Your message is marked with high priority. Do you need this? This just adds into one of the scoring metrics in a spam filter. Spam is often marked with high priority, so your message will be treated with more scrutiny. On the otherhand, for some filters marking your message with high priority will mean less scrutiny.
- `IsBodyHTML` is marked true, but you're only providing `text/html`. You minimally need to include an alternate view with `text/plain`.

  ```
  message.IsBodyHtml = true;
  string html = RegisterMessageBodyHtml(recvrName, verCode,NewUserID);
  string plain = RegisterMessageBodyPlaintext(recvrName, verCode, NewUserID);
  message.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, new ContentType("text/html"));
  message.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(plain, new ContentType("text/plain"));
  ```
- See how Google treats your message. In gmail, open a test message that you've sent,  click the downfacing arrow next to the reply button, and select "Show Original". You'll see how Google treated your message. Look for headers like:

  ```
  Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning xxx@xxx.org does not designate xx.xx.xx.xx as permitted sender) client-ip=xx.xx.xx.xx;
  Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning xxx@xxx.org does not designate xx.xx.xx.xx as permitted sender)
  ```
- Read up on the default rule set for SpamAssassin as it will probably be a good reference on the rule sets for most filters. If you can identify why your message is getting flagged, you can fix it.

Comment: Thanks Greg. +1 for a great explaination. I will check according your guidelines. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for this.  What did the trick for me was the required plain text view.

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'RegisterMessageBodyHtml' does not exist

Answer (score 9):

**Emails Marked as Spam**

This is not a programming issue unfortunately, but I can understand why you might think it is.  The *code* is sending the emails, and they have been sent as you reported. So this is highly unlikely to be a problem with your code, because it's served it's purpose fully!

**Getting around it**

It all comes down to the recipients mail client (the software they are using to view the emails with), or the services that process the emails at some sort of gateway, or a combination of both of these!

All of these elements have vastly varied algorithms and metrics for determining if an email is probably spam or not.  So a one fit all solution is sadly not possible.  Some are intelligent, other less so, some brutally discard a huge % of emails, others operate purely on a 'not on white list, you're not getting in' policy, and then there are those that just let everything come in regardless of content/origin.

The ways to go around fixing this are:

- To try and get on white lists for major email providers.
- Educate your audience to add the senders email address as a trusted contact.
- Check your mail server IP isn't blacklisted by some providers.  It's possible your IP address was previously used to send spam.
- Experiment with the emails content

Comment: Thanks Tom. I have tested on Gmail and Yahoo. So do you think Gmail is marked as blacklisted.

Comment: Surely it's not programming issue. Here is another piece of advice:
1. Change email account - it's already on black lists
2. Don't send emails so often. Make some queue and dispatch one per for example 1 minute. Sending a lot of messages in a short time quickly lead to be recognized as a spammer

Comment: @Irfan, possibly, it's hard to know.  I think though it's more likely to be their intelligent spam filters.  Try changing your content/the source, or send them an email asking to be white listed.

Answer (score 5):

Your from address is invalid. Try putting in a real email address that points to a valid mailbox. Preferably this email address is on the same domain as the SMTP server you use to send the mail with. If not, read into SPF http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Comment: Thanks buddy!!! you have provided a very useful information. But let me explain, i m extracting mailer email from configuration file. In MailAddress(emailID, "Panbeli.in...") emailID is a variable that gets address from configuration file. Second parameter is the title.

Comment: @InfraRaza I was sort of guessing yes, don't know what your configuration value is. Whatever is configured there might be the cause though.

Answer (score 5):

This happen to me to and it's solved now,
I just set the BodyEncoding and SubjectEncoding proprieties on the MailMessage object,
and added the DOCTYPE and the html tags to my email header,

```
var msg = new MailMessage
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default,
        IsBodyHtml = true
    };

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

It's working perfectly now

Comment: How did you add the headers to your email message?

Answer (score 2):

Add following line in your code while creating `MailMessage`

```
    msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot even for the house hold names. I sympathise with you as you only want a plain text email but if your clients really want those emails and you really want your logo in then they could just white list your domain so that all emails get through!

We use a company called mailchimp for sending out subscriber mails and I questioned them on how to avoid spam filters especially in the context of essentially an advert out to a large group it can be very difficult to avoid them, here is their advice and there is lots of it.;

[Avoiding the Spam Filters](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/avoiding-the-spam-filters/)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem, it looks like Google mark as spam any mails using the default ASP.NET e-mail authentication subject and body. I.e.:

"Please confirm your account by clicking here."

Changing the text allows the e-mail to pass the spam filter