# how to send email without go to spam mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

```
        MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress("test@smtp.com");
        MailAddress mailTo = new MailAddress("tester@gmail.com");
        MailMessage mail2 = new MailMessage(mailFrom, mailTo);
        mail2.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.Host = "xxx.xx.xx.xxx"; // smtp host ip
        mail2.Subject = "Testing.";
        mail2.Body = "Hello";
        mail2.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail2.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        client.Send(mail2);
```

the above is my function that use to send an email via smtp, but I realized all the mail was located in my spam mail folder (Gmail). Is there anyway that can solve it ?

Comment: Use System.Net.NetworkCredential with valid mailID and password

Comment: here is it answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079902/c-net-messages-are-going-to-spam-folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042309/email-messages-going-to-spam-folder

Comment: still the same result.

Comment: Are you actually using `test@smtp.com` as a sender address? The domain smtp.com uses SPF which states that all senders (which don't use their list of accepted servers) should soft-fail, which means that they state that "anyone claiming that they send from *@smtp.com from unauthorized server should be tagged as bad/spam".

Answer (score 3):

1. `IsBodyHTML` is marked true, but you're only providing text/html. You minimally need to     include an alternate view with text

   mail2.Body = "Hello";
2. make sure you not using Mail from and mailto is same address or

   `MailMessage mail2 = new MailMessage(mailFrom, mailTo);`

**UPDATE**

```
 mail2.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.Host = "xxx.xx.xx.xxx"; // smtp host ip
        mail2.Subject = "Testing.";
        mail2.Body = "Hello";
        string html = "html";
        // here is example to user AlternateViews 

        mail2.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html"));
        string Plaintext ="plain text";
        mail2.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Plaintext, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/plain"));
        mail2.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail2.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        client.Send(mail2);
```

Comment: how to include an alternate view with text ?

Comment: still the same result.

Comment: Added alternate views with html and text. Still no luck.

Comment: also no solution for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this and revert.

```
string mailServer;
int port;
string mailId, mailPass;
string subject;
string mailTo;
subject="something";
StringBuilder mailBody = new StringBuilder();
mailTo = "someone@gmail.com";
mailServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
mailId = "something@gmail.com";
myString.Length = 0;
myString.Append("<html><body><div>BODY CONTENT</div></body></html>");
mailPass = "xxxxxx";
port = 587;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(mailId, mailTo, subject, myString.ToString());
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(mailServer, port);
System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(mailId, mailPass);
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = nc;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: I updated the answer. Please check it up and revert.